# How to read and extract a particular sentence present within a double quote after matching with a string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a file with lots of data. Inside that file there is a word Description. I want to read a line present within a double quote after that description only.
For example :Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".

First I want to search the word description. Then I need to read the line "Invalid character value for cast specification".

How can I do that?

Comment: So, the file is lines with a single `key: "desc"` per line?

Comment: It is not clear to me what this file contains. Description and text in double quotes on same line, on two lines, on even more lines? Is this contained one or serveral time in this file? Please show us a real example of the file content.

Answer (score 1):

Use regular expressions, in this case Regex.Match should work nicely.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...
public static readonly REGEX_QUOTEFINDER = @"{0}\s*""(?<QUOTE>([^""]+))""";
public static string ReadQuotedString(string blob, string key)
{
    return Regex.Match(
        blob, 
        string.Format(REGEX_QUOTE, Regex.Escape(key))
    ).Groups["QUOTE"].Value;
}
...
string result = ReadQuotedString(File.ReadAllText("c:/test.txt"), ":Description:");
```

Something like the above will probably do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
var data = @"key:""desc""
key2: ""d2""
key2: ""d2""";

var keyValues = Regex
  .Matches(data, @"^(?<key>.*?): *""(?<value>.*)""", RegexOptions.Multiline)
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(m => new{
                   key = m.Groups["key"].Value, 
                   value = m.Groups["value"].Value});

foreach(var kv in keyValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", kv.key, kv.value);
}
```

Comment: This is pretty intense. I'm trying to figure out what the second `?` is doing here - doesn't the `*` make it redundant?

Comment: @Jeff : No, `*?` is the lazy version of `*`, so it will stop at the first encountered `:` rather than subsequent occurrences.